# Update Coredata Attributes without Duplication

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, ios7

I have 3 textfields-Name,Age,Phone Number
Every time i entering the values on each fields will be stored on core data

Also i want to check any repetition in my db, that is

- First i want to check there is any repetition in Name
- If any repetition, then check the age and phone number.
- If age is same it can not be change.
- If the difference in phone number, second number will replace the first phone Number.

I tried a lot..
pls help me

My Code is

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Name" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entityDescc];
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sname like %@ ",self.nameTextField.text];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error;
NSArray *matchingData=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (matchingData.count<=0) {
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Name" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newObject=[[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [newObject setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"sname"];
    [newObject setValue:self.ageTextField.text forKey:@"age"];
    NSError *error;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
else{
     int count=0;
     for (record *obj in matchingData) {
        NSEntityDescription *entityDescc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Name" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
        [request setEntity:entityDescc];

NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age like %@ ",self.ageTextField.text];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
 NSError *error;
NSArray *matchingData=[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];




          if (matchingData.count<=0) {

              NSLog(@"Entered");
              NSEntityDescription *entityDesc=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Name" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
              NSManagedObject *newObject=[[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entityDesc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


              [newObject setValue:self.ageTextField.text forKey:@"age"];


              NSError *error;
              [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
          }
          ++count;
        }
     }
```

it is not check the attribute Age

Comment: what is the attribute name used for your _phone number_ ? and also name of variable name of your _phone number_ `textfield`.

Answer (score 0):

Save all three details in single entity. Fetch all records in the given entity, with out any predicate. Create a model class for each record. Do your business logic using the model class list. This will solve your problem and will make your app perform better.